# Accessing band n of GeoTIFF using gdal_merge.py?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-merge

How does `gdal_merge.py` want input bands of a multiband tiff pathed via the --optfile option?

I am merging a large list of .tifs via a subprocess.call in python:

```
gdal_merge.py -o "target" --optfile "fileIn"
```

where "fileIn" is a list of input files. But playing around I can't seem to find how to reference example.tif Band_1, for example. So even more simply, how do you call a specific band of a multiband geotiff in gdal?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Would you like to extract n-th band or specify the order of the input files?

Comment: thanks. i'm trying to merge many bands of the same type into one mosaic, and all the files have the same structure. so file1.tif has 1000 bands, and i have 100 .tifs. So i want to merge file1.tif/band_1 with all other band_1s from the other 100 files, and then do that for every band. but at its simplest, i can't figure out how, in gdal_merge, to path file1.tf/band_1!

Comment: Just a comment, because I'd have to check, but it seems that you will have to break the 100 tifs into separate bands and then merge them back.

Answer (score 5):

You can't tell [`gdal_merge.py`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) to process a specific band from multiband rasters as it doesn't support a `-b band` argument or `path/to/file.tif/band_num` syntax.

I would use [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) then [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdalbuildvrt -b 1 -input_file_list "file_list.txt" "target.vrt"
gdal_translate "target.vrt" "target.tif"
```

Or without an intermediate VRT file:

```
gdalbuildvrt -b 1 -input_file_list "file_list.txt" /vsistdout/ | gdal_translate /vsistdin/ "target.tif"
```

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation of gdal_merge.py and the alternative solution. I didn't know the gdalbuildvrt would mosaic files spatially. Awesome.

Comment: ok, sort of awesome. seems to be taking much longer than my previous routine that used gdal_merge.py. Any idea if the gdal_merge.py routine would be able to take a NetCDF file with a similar Band_n format?

Comment: Weird, I've always found gdalbuildvrt + gdal_translate to be much faster than gdal_merge.py.  Did you try the 1st method without the intermediate vrt? Don't know,  depends on whether the netcdf file uses subdatasets http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html